# how do I get past dpkg --configure stall with base files

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

We have 2 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server hosts in a remote datacenter stalling at the same place while trying to upgrade with apt:

```
admin@location-a:~$ sudo apt upgrade
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
admin@location-a:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-server:
 ubuntu-server depends on motd-news-config; however:
  Package motd-news-config is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up base-files (10.1ubuntu2.10) ...
```

I have killed the operation and rebooted a few times (hence the `interrupted`) - oddly, repeated searching has found no way around this problem. Is there any way I can "reset" theses boxes to a known good state?

When trying to fix the `motd-news-config` fail, same thing:

```
admin@location-a:~$ sudo apt install motd-news-config
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  motd-news-config
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 376 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,484 B of archives.
After this operation, 43.0 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up base-files (10.1ubuntu2.10) ...
```

Being a base-files package issue this smells like OS death to me...

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04.  Did you ever find a solution?